# binding a datagridview in background(or using a thread) in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, backgroundworker

I have a list (of type class). It has several rows..44000 for example, and I need to bind it to a datagridview in c#. I wanna do it without taking the control of the UI from the user. Even when I am using a background worker, the title bar says not responding.

its as simple as

dataGridView1.DataSource = bars; where bars is a bindinglist which has 44000 rows.

This single line is clogging up all the UI and the time..

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `bars` preloaded in a thread?

Comment: This is always going to be difficult, because you have to update the UI in the UI thread but you want to effectively pause to process UI events like redraws from time to time. Have you tried setting the DataSource to be an empty ObservableCollection, then getting a BackgroundWorker to raise a series of requests to the UI thread to add the items to that collection in more suitably-sized chunks?

Comment: Review your AutoSizeColumn properties.

Comment: Can you show how you are implementing your background worker?  And what is the type "bars" data... DataTable, List<>, etc.

Comment: .Yes bars is pre-loaded.
FYI:

public class Bar
{
 public DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }
 public decimal Open { get; set; }
 public decimal Close { get; set; }
}

BindingList<Bar> bars;

I load up bars at the server and send it across to the client and its almost instant. 

I have run the app in debug and the line

dataGridView1.DataSource = bars;

is taking all the UI control. I could choose to run datagridview in virtual mode and implement all of its functions..but..is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is on binding smaller batches with the ones in view or will be near in view only. And dynamically as the user scroll, update this binding list.

There isn't a perfect solution as the size of your list is so long, binding the whole thing one way or the other will yield performance hit.